# Wildcard that matches whitespaces only

Tags: mysql

Is there a wildcard that matches whitespaces only? I'm trying to find all records that looks like:

```
Berlin  DE
Munchen  DE
London        GB
```

Thats my query:

```
SELECT
    cities_aliases.alias,
    cities_aliases.id as alias_id,
    cities.id as clean_id,
    cities.city,
    cities.country
FROM
    cities_aliases,
    cities
WHERE
    LOWER(cities_aliases.alias) LIKE CONCAT(cities.city,'WILDCARD_THAT_MATCHES_WHITESPACES_ONLY', LOWER(cities.country))
    AND
    cities.country = cities_aliases.country
    AND
    cities_aliases.citycode IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a wildcard cannot be defined it is always 'anything'.

However, you can achieve the what you want to by using the [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function.

This can be slow as it will usually cause a full table scan and if you've got a large data set it might take some time.

for example:

```
SELECT city FROM cities
WHERE city REGEXP 'London\s*GB'
```